# C#/JSON conversion to PHP script

Tags: c#, php, json

I need to extract data from a website's REST api, but I've never worked with it, and I'm just getting back into coding again after some time. But I need to get this project moving in a forward direction very quickly, and cannot for the life of me, figure out how to convert this C#/JSON string into a php equivalent script to poll for the data I need...

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}",UserName, Password))));
```

I'm thinking I need to use curl for this, but again, it's been a long time, and I'm a little rusty. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go ahead and try to use cUrl http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php which is used to make calls with the different to an API.

There is also this library which is based on cUrl.
https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class and some samples from the site.

```
//For making a GET request
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->get('https://www.example.com/');

//For making a POST request
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->post('https://www.example.com/login/', array(
  'username' => 'myusername',
  'password' => 'mypassword',
));  

//With custom headers
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->setBasicAuthentication('username', 'password');
```

Comment: This got me alot closer to what I need, but I still have issues with the Username/Password encoding. For now, I've had to encode the password in a C# compiler and hard code it into my script.. if anyone can figure out how to solve that problem as well, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way with $_GET['pass'], $_GET['user']

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
response = webClient.DownloadString("https://example.com/code.php?pass=password&user=username");
Console.Write(response);
```

Comment: Um... 1) NEVER pass a password in the URL, and 2) I need to SEND the username+password to someone else's server, not my own, and it has to be in the HEADER information sent to the server (which actually confuses me)

Comment: Server owner can see your header if want. For what you using server when you don't trust hosting or server provider :) it silly. You can open https://www.openshift.com vps (app) for free. 1) if you install ssl it does not matter.